# Does the orthogonal projection of a vector onto a subspace equal the original vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, projection

I've come to the conclusion that a vector equals its orthogonal projection onto a subspace by the following:

Since by orthogonal decomposition a vector "y" can be written uniquely as the sum of its projection "p" onto a subspace, and a vector (y - p) orthogonal to the subspace. I have y = p + (y - p). So then I can say the inner product of p and (y - p) is the inner product of p & y minus the inner product of p & p, which is equal to zero. So inner product of p & y equals inner product of p & p, and y = p.
I'm a student and I cannot be sure that this is correct with my knowledge of linear algebra, and I was interested in finding out if what I just proved is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\langle p, y\rangle = \langle p, p \rangle$ does **not** imply $y=p$.
For example, $p=(1,0)$ and $y=(1,1)$.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the simple explanation. I am wondering if there could be a way to prove true a case where ***y*** does equal its projection ***p***, and for such a case what would the premises have to be (i.e. in what kind of a vector space does ***y*** and ***p*** exist?). Sorry if the wordings aren't clear. I have a vague geometric representation of this in my mind that is hard to write in words.

Comment: @WonRhim $y$ equals its projection $p$ if and only if $y$ already lies in the subspace that you are projecting onto